# Clone an aws environment so that it shares the same RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment called 'blue' that is my live production environment. I want to clone this environment to create a new environment called 'green' that I will use for development.

How can I clone 'blue' so that the clone uses the same RDS database?

Once I have got the 'green' environment working as a perfect copy of 'blue' I will upload the development code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know cloning the RDS host isn't possible from the clone interface.

What I've done:
Create a saved config from your blue environment.
Create a snapshot of the blue database.
Under saved configs, launch an environment called green using the blue config.
Under RDS you can choose the snapshot you took for spinning up the host.
Then at the end you can use [elasticbeanstalk's blue-green url swap](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html).

Know that this will result in potential data loss if there are any writes to the database between when you snapshotted and when you do the url swap they will only exist on the previous host.

To mitigate that you could instead create your environments without the RDS host being part of them, and then 'share' the host between the 2 environments during your deployment.